# How do I verify eligibility for AWS free tier using API call?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking to verify AWS free tier eligibility using an API call. I can find how to do this in the AWS Management Console, but not via an API call.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Billing Alarm to notify you if your usage exceeds the free tier. Basically, you create a billing alarm that is set to notify you if your cost exceeds $0.01 for the billing period. There is a guide that shows the steps at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-alarms.html

CloudWatch Billing Metrics are available via the AWS API.